# How to assign a method parameter to a property using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: objective-c, appcode

Is there a way to assign a method parameter to a property using a keyboard command?  I try to use "Extract Field" in this case, but the IDE errors out.  A common use case is assigning properties out of an object's constructor.

```
-(id)initWithVariable:(NSNumber*)variable {
   self = [super init];
   if ( self ) {
       // Need a way to do this with a keyboard command:
       self.variable = variable
   }
   return self;
}
```

Right now, the best way I can find to do this is to physically type out `self.variable = variable` and then do a [Alt] + [Enter] to add the property that way, but it would nice to not have to type this rote information out into the IDE each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type:
`variable;`
Then you can do Extract property and get what you want.

Comment: That is simpler than what I've been doing, thanks!  I wish there was a way to avoid even that step.